# eclipse acting weird when creating methods

Tags: java, oop, eclipse

I don't see what could be wrong here, I was working on a different method but had some problems so I tried to simplify it to check where could the mistake be but I ended going up into this very simple method and still I have the same error.

[image]

When I put the mouse over the redX at line 6 I get a message saying:

```
multiple markers at this line
 -Syntax error on token "(",;expected 
 -Syntax error on token ")",;expected`
```

mouse at line 7 says:

```
void method cannot return a value
2 quick fixes available
change method return type to 'int'
change to 'return;'
```

I changed public static void to public static int and also changed the method's modifier but the error at line 6 appears everytime.
I don't see anything wrong here but I think I'm making a mistake that just needs a simple fix, am I going crazy? never had this particular problem before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring a method called `y` *within* the `main` method. In Java, you cannot nest method declerations.

You will have to move it outside the `main` method scope or else, declare a private inner class which will hold your `y` method.

In short:

```
public class gat {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ...
    }

    int y(int a) {
        return a + 5;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class gat {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        class inner { 
            int y (int a) {
                return a + 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first approach is the most common, however you sometimes do end up using the second approach, especially when dealing with Swing Events and other threading aspects.